# Python class binding not working, throws errors

Tags: python, class, binding

So I've been watching a video tutorial on classes in Python, and the code looks like this:

```
class MyPythonClass():

    def _init_(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.print_msg()

    def print_msg(self):
        print(self.msg)


inst = MyPythonClass('hello')
```

That's copied pretty much verbatim, and the code works in the video. But when using it as above in Eclipse workspace, i get the following error:

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

And, when using it with the class method `print_msg('hello')` instead, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: say_hello() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I only passed 1 string argument, not 2 arguments, right..

Btw, the tutorial I think uses around Python 3.1, while I'm using Python 3.6.

Why do I get these errors?

Comment: `_init_` -> `__init__`

Comment: superb; i thought i'd change it to my liking, but think i read later it's a built in name, thanks for reminding me, it was all in 1 day;

Answer (score 2):

Read `__init__` as "dunder init" and you'll never forget that the special method names begin and end with *two* underlines!